# Issue with Content Provider in Monodroid

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have created an android application in xamarin which has a custom application class.

```
[Application(Label="Demo")]
public class CustomApplication : Application
{
    public CustomApplication (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
            : base (handle, transfer)
    {
    }

    public CustomApplication()
    {
    }
}
```

Now I have created a Content Provider with some permissions in Manifest file.
My app is running fine and I am able to query with content provider if I don't have custom application class in my app. But if I use custom application class along with content provider then my app is not even opening. Basically I need my app to serve as Content Provider.
Need some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you added permissions to the `Application` node in the AndroidManifest.xml it is going to get overriden as soon as you create your own `Application` class and attribute it with the `Application` flag. You can read more about the `Application` flag [in the Xamarin docs](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.App.ApplicationAttribute).